# content porter not working after upgrade to 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

We have two CM servers load balanced in our development environment. We upgraded Development environment from 2011 sp1 HR2 to 2013 sp1.

After the upgrade, we are not able to use load balanced url to connect from content porter client 2013 sp1. We get the error:

> Could not connect to ImportExport service on SDL Tridion Content
>   Manager server

If we use individual urls on http instead of https then connection works.

Can you please suggest what are we missing?

Comment: Have you followed the installation manual and uninstalled the Content Porter before upgrade and installed the compatible version after? The best way to troubleshoot is to use some network profile, like Fiddler to see what's going on, or try to connect to the server directly, without the balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For content porter to work using bigip on https, the workaround was provided by SDL support team.

The workaround was to modify `web.config file for coreservice` to use security mechanism of `tranport instead of transportwithmessagecredentials` for basichttp binding.

The side effect of this change: site or content porter no longer works on http, only works on https.