# Could not connect to ImportExport service on SDL Tridion Content Manager server <IP address>

Tags: 2013, content-manager, content-porter-2013

I'm in the process of deploying our latest changes to our UAT environment. I'm using SDL Content Porter 2013 SP1 to import my schema changes but every time I try to connect with the server I get an error:

> Could not connect to ImportExport service on SDL Tridion Content Manager server <*IP Address*>.

As far as I could tell, no recent changes have been made to the server.

I've made sure that the credentials are correct. I've tried to RDC to the UAT CM server and I'm able to get in which suggests that the connection is fine. I've restarted IIS and recycled the App pool just to be sure. I found that 2013 SP1 doesn't have a Tridion Content Porter Service as it's added straight into 2013.

I've also checked Google but the majority of posts are referring to 2009 Content Porter and missing hotfixes which (as far as I know) does not relate to 2013 SP1.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Are there eany errors logged in the Tridion event log on the CMS server?

Comment: I've checked Event Viewer and there are no errors logged for Tridion.

Comment: ImportExport service is hosted in the TcmServiceHost. Is it running? Tridion version 2013 Sp1 ?

Comment: The TcmServiceHost is running and yes it is Tridion 2013 SP1.

Comment: Maybe the IIS log and/or an HTTP trace (e.g. Fiddler) of the client-server traffic can shine a light on how it fails?

Comment: Did you check that the license file for Content Porter is valid? For instance open cp_license.xml in the <Tridion_Dir>/Content Porter/bin/ and check the expiration date.

Comment: Is the server name and protocol correct? For example, I sometimes forget to remove the "http://" from the server name.

Comment: I've checked the license and it's valid. I've checked the server name and protocol and that's correct (because I've been able to content port to this very server two weeks ago and nothing has changed). I'll be checking the IIS log and/or an HTTP trace and report what I find. Thank you for all of your suggestions.

Comment: Good luck, Tim. I double-checked the actual error for invalid names and it's _not_ related to your issue. I noted so in a [separate Q&A](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/11280/46). There's one other TRex Q&A with the same error related to "bigip" if you didn't see it: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7563/46.