# Content Porter Server Name Issue (Solved)

Tags: content-porter-2013

I commented on this question on Server Names for Content Porter:
[Could not connect to ImportExport service on SDL Tridion Content Manager server <IP address>](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/11240/46)

The actual error for entering "http://" in the Server Name for Content Porter was not really related to that question, so I'm posting the error and reason in this separate Q & (community) A.

I sometimes get the following in Content Porter when setting up an export:

```
---------------------------
SDL Content Porter 2013 SP1
---------------------------
System.Exception: Server name has invalid value.

Server name cannot be empty and must contain only alphanumeric characters.

   at Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.SelectServerPresenter.CreateServerInfo(String protocol, String name, String port, String description)

   at Tridion.ContentPorter.Presenters.SelectServerPresenter.SaveServer()
```

I added the reason below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDL Content Porter Server information pop-up takes the following:

- Protocol
- Port
- Name
- Description

The `name` should just be the server name (domain). For example in training we use `cms.electridion.com`. Entering `http://cms.electridion.com` will give you the above error.